# Add folder to zip

Tags: powershell, zip, directory

I am facing a problem how to add folder to existing ZIP file.

This zip file is created by PowerShell also.

I can only use system classes provided by Powershell 5. I cannot use any of user packages or plugins (7zip included).

Here is my code:

```
function addFileToArchiveTest ($filePathToAdd, $archivePathToUpdate) {
    if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($filePathToAdd) -or (Test-Path $filePathToAdd)) {
        $file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePathToAdd);
        Write-Host $filePathToAdd.Name;
        Write-Host $filePathToAdd;
        Write-Host $archivePathToUpdate;
        $archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($archivePathToUpdate, [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update);
        $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::NoCompression;
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($archive, $filePathToAdd, $file, "$compressionLevel");
        $archive.Dispose();
    } else {
        Write-Host "[ERROR@function] <AddFileToArchive>: <filePathToAdd> does not exist!";
        Write-Host "[ERROR@function] <Variable<filePathToAdd>>: $filePathToAdd";
        Write-Host "[ERROR@function] <Variable<archivePathToUpdate>>: $archivePathToUpdate";
    }
}
```

I am thinking about variable `$file` - there might be a problem, because folder doesn't have an extension.

I run script like this:

```
PS> addFileToArchiveTest "C:\TestFolder\FolderToArchive" "C:\TestFolder\thereIsAlreadyZipFile.zip"
```

It returns with error:

```
Exception calling "CreateEntryFromFile" with "4" argument(s): "Access to the
path 'C:\TestFolder\FolderToArchive' is denied."
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\testfolder.ps1:196 char:13
+             [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFro ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Noted I also try allow script and I am launching with admin rights.

Comment: PowerShell 5 does support Compress-Archive. It does exactly what you want

Comment: @guiwhatsthat: Thank is actually working. Thank you very much. For others - I noticed, that Compress-Archive (param -Update) cannot process file bigger than 2GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @guiwhatsthat answered: PowerShell 5 does support Compress-Archive. It does exactly what you want.

That is working as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps surprisingly, `CreateEntryFromFile()` is for adding *files*, not *folders*. You need to add each file individually:

```
Get-ChildItem $filePathToAdd | ForEach-Object {
    [IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($archive, $_.FullName, $_.Name, "$compressionLevel")
}
```